# How to navigate to previous records depending on textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a button on my **form** whenever I click on it, it creates several **records** including a column named: **[Aantal]**, if aantal says 5, it will create 5 records. This **column** is also as a **textbox** named **[Aantal]** on the form.

After the records are created it goes to the **last** **record** as shown here:

```
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "GeleidelijstForm", acLast
```

Is it possible to make it navigate to the **first record** of those **5** created?

So not the very first record in the table, but the first of those just created. For example if **[Aantal]** is **5**, make it go back **4** records, that way it will be on the first of the **5** records it just created.

**Edit:**

I have something like this that goes to the latest record, now I want it to go to the first record instead:

```
pgn = Me.CurrentRecord
t1 = Nz(Me.Aantal, 1)
If t1 > 1 Then
t2 = pgn + t1 - 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `acPrevious` and `acNext` instead of `acLast`. See: [AcRecord enumeration (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acrecord). But you must make the calculation of how many times you must move to get to the desired record yourself. Access does not know which records you've just created.

```vb
Dim t1 As Long, i As Long

t1 = Clng(Nz(Me.Aantal, 1))

DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "GeleidelijstForm", acLast
For i = 1 To t1 - 1
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "GeleidelijstForm", acPrevious
Next i
```

Or you can directly jump to it with

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim t1 As Long, numRecords As Long

t1 = Clng(Nz(Me.Aantal, 1))
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.MoveLast
numRecords = rs.RecordCount
rs.Close

DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "GeleidelijstForm", acGoTo, numRecords - t1 + 1
```

---

You can also jump to a specific record like this in case you are able to identify the record by some value

```vb
Dim rs As Object

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
rs.FindFirst "[MyID] = " & theId
If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
rs.Close
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am not trying to go to a specific record depending on value that I can equal to another value. The reason I have it as acLast is so that it goes to the newest record created. But my create button creates 6 new records if my [Aantal] textbox says 6. And I want it to go to record 1 of 6 instead of 6 of 6. Please see my edit.

Comment: I think that I have answered the question by saying that you can use `acPrevious`, but I'll add more details...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RecordsetClone` and loop backwards a number of times. Something like:

```
Private Sub cmdPos_Click()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    lngCount = Me!txtPos - 1
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.MoveLast
    If lngCount > 0 Then    '   if only one record added then no need to loop
        For lngLoop1 = 1 To lngCount
            rs.MovePrevious
        Next lngLoop1
    End If
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "cmdPos_Click", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, it probably would be faster/cleaner to do that!!